# The hierarchy of the type CLASSNAME is inconsistent when extending DefaultFtpSessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I'm brand new to Spring, and I'm facing a real problem, and I didn't know how to solve

when I extend `DefaultFtpSessionFactory`, the compiler gets annoyed telling me that `The hierarchy of the type CLASSNAME is inconsistent`.

I searched a lot and found that this could happen when there are classes that are needed, which are not in the Build path.

Does anybody know the how-to deal with such compilation issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the line that's giving the error.

Comment: Since I can't post a snapshot here, I'll write it                                                                                                                  `public class FtpClass extends DefaultFtpsSessionFactory ` it give `The hierarchy of the type CLASSNAME is inconsistent` right under `FtpClass`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you use some useful Dependency Management tool, like Maven or Gradle and have `spring-integration-ftp` as a dependency for your project and allow that tool to pick up the required transitive dependencies.

Comment: I tried this way, but unfortunately nothing has changed.